# Laravel - Display selection list menu options depending on the users company_id

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to find a way to show only options in a select menu that belong to a users company.

I have relationships step up between user, user_profile, company, and department.

Now on my user_profile edit for I want to be able to select a department from the department list.
But the list should only contain the departments that belong to the users company.

Here is my the edit function of my UserProfilesController

```
public function edit($username)
{
    $user = User::with('user_profile.company', 'user_profile.location', 'user_profile.department', 'user_profile.title')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();

    $companies = Company::lists('name', 'id'); //get companies for drop menu
    $locations = Location::lists('name', 'id'); //get locations for drop menu
    $departments = Department::lists('name', 'id'); //get departments for drop menu
    $titles = Title::lists('name', 'id'); //get titles for drop menu
    //dd($user->toArray());
    return View::make('user_profiles.edit', compact('user', 'companies', 'locations', 'departments', 'titles'));
}
```

How can I query this on the $departments variable? Is there a Laravel way? Right now I'm getting all of the departments. I just want to get the departments that belong to the users company.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `Company hasMany Department` relation setup:

```
$departments = $user->user_profile->company->departments->lists('name', 'id');
```

Also I suggest renaming your relations to camelCase, since this is how Eloquent reads them as dynamic properties.

That being said, you can't do this, unless you explicitly load (`with` or `load`) the relation:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->user_profile; // null

// but if relation was userProfile, then you can do either:
$user->userProfile;
$user->user_profile; // this could be called as a dynamic property, but stick to 1 convention
```

Comment: Ahh I see now, that did the trick. Thanks! Also thanks for the tip on the camelCase.